# GPA prediction of college student

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-cleaning

I have a dataset consist of 8 columns and 15600 rows with the following columns:-

> 1.Entry_academic_year which have 5 discrete value (2558,2559,2560,2561,2562)
>
> 2.Faculty (It is the faculty that student has taken like engineering)
>
> 3.branch  (It is the branch  that student has taken like software engineering)
>
> 4.Admission type (how the student enter the college)
>
> 5.Graduated_high_school (it is the high school where student got graduated)
>
> 6.province_of_school
>
> 7.GPA_high_school(It is the GPA of student in high school)
>
> 8.GPA_college(It is the GPA of the student during college)

I am trying to predict the GPA of the student at the college by dividing the GPA into 4 quartiles with respect to percentile (25,50,75), The problem I faced is that the Graduated_high_school columns have around 1732 unique value with some school contain only one row which makes the prediction around 30-35 % accuracy

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can see if `Graduated_high_school` is correlated in any way to `GPA_college`? If there is no correlation, you can try to fit a model by dropping the `Graduated_high_school` column.

Else, you can try to drop rows belonging to under-represented high schools. However, one problem I foresee is that future predictions might have `Graduated_high_school` that are unseen in the training dataset, leading to problems (e.g. schools that weren't mentioned in the dataset, or if someone  decides to use your model, on a dataset from another country). So, if the `Graduated_high_school` is not important, I would consider dropping it altogether.

Or, maybe you can change `Graduated_high_school` to something else that is related, such as number of teachers in high school, teacher-student ratio etc.